# gdb: interrupt running process without killing child processes

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, parent-child

I have a process (call it process A) which kicks off several instances of process B. When debugging process A in gdb, if I use Ctrl+C to pause process A with a SIGINT, all the child B processes get killed, so I have to restart the whole thing once I'm done debugging process A. Is there a way to prevent gdb from sending SIGINT to the child processes, thus killing them (at least I assume that's what's happening)? If so, what is it?

Note that I do NOT have the source code for process B (so I cannot add some code to handle SIGINT). The process interfaces are in C++.

Comment: I feel like such a question has probably been asked before, but I was unable to find anything on SO or search engines. Sorry if duplicate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```

in A. According to `man signal` (emphasis mine),

> A  child created via fork(2) inherits a copy of its parent's signal dispositions.  During an execve(2), the dispositions of handled signals are reset  to  the  default;  **the dispositions of ignored signals are left unchanged**.

Comment: Since you said "try" I feel like I should add that this does, in fact, work. A separate call to `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);` also seems unnecessary for gdb to stop in process A.